# Do native speakers use phrases like "a hard date" or "a hard stop"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

Recently, I've come across these two expressions with the unusual usage of the adjective *hard*:

> We've reached **a hard date**.
>
> You have **a hard stop** on what you can access.

In this context, I guess, it has a similar meaning to *closing date* or *deadline*, and *hard* itself means nonnegotiable.

---

From *the Cambridge Dictionary*

> hard adjective (**CLEAR**)
> ​[ before noun ] **able to be proved**:
> hard facts/evidence

---

I looked up the two phrases in COCA and found out that they're both very, very rarely used.

---

So, do this sentences sound fine to you, or is there a more natural way to convey a similar meaning?

Comment: I'm more used to 'a firm date' (various senses) / 'a firm block'.

Comment: As a native (British) speaker, I cannot say that I have come across either, although I have often heard 'hard' being used in very similar ways usually indicating something either immovable or inflexible, as opposed to something physically hard.

Comment: @LeeLeon could you please give an example of such use? I'm not sure about  other _correct_ phrases.

Comment: "between a rock and a **hard** place", "**hard** coding", "**hard** wired", "**hard**-headed" (stubborn)

Comment: TV programs, especially where someone's being interviewed:  "We're coming up on a hard break".  This means an ad is coming on over which the anchor has no control.

Comment: I’ve had a few dates that were excruciatingly hard )to get through)…

Comment: Hard date and firm date are slightly different. Having "a firm date" means that the exact date has been specified e.g. for a meeting or event (in contrast to a "provisional/tentative date" where you expect it will change), but it doesn't indicate that this date is final and unchangeable (although it might be some effort to change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both expressions appear to be used in business. [The Ridiculous Business Jargon Dictionary: H-words](http://www.theofficelife.com/business-jargon-dictionary-H.html) defines "hard stop" as:

> The non-negotiable end of a meeting. Usually announced at the start. "Clients are visiting this afternoon so we have a hard stop at two."

While I have not been able to find a definition for "hard date", it pretty clearly means a date or deadline for something that cannot be delayed. It often is contrasted with "soft date", which is its opposite. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7dcNBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq="hard+date") is an example of the phrase in use.

I think the corresponding definition of "hard" used here is this one from the OED:

> Of a business transaction or negotiation: strict, exact; allowing no compromise or concession; (of an opinion, policy, etc.) uncompromising; inflexible. Cf. hard bargain n. 2, hard line n. 2.

Answer (score 0):

*Hard deadline* is widely used to mean a final, unchangeable deadline.  *Hard date* is (IMO) less common, but can also refer to an unchangeable *start* date.

*Hard stop* has several meanings: [an uncushioned mechanical end stop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hard_stop);  a fixed end time; [a complete and abrupt stop of a vehicle](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wioDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22hard+stop%22+racing&source=bl&ots=Q9T7W73-yR&sig=yBCd19DO1utzTurg_Ym1vaaKt-4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA0JT4qrXZAhVKrlQKHVIzDBoQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=%22hard%20stop%22%20racing&f=false) (similar to "dead stop"); and a [police tactic](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-25373505/how-do-the-police-carry-out-a-hard-stop) surprising a suspect.

(Answer based on UK usage)